# Chart C# remove numbers and add range

Tags: c#, graph, charts

My questions:

1. How can I remove these numbers that I marked in the screenshot https://prnt.sc/116tvvz?
2. How do I specify the range of numbers on the chart? For example, here's a screenshot https://prnt.sc/116txqs. It shows numbers in the range of 50.000-60.000, but the graph starts from zero to 60.000.

Comment: could you share some code

Comment: I did not change the chart in any way programmatically. I just fill it with data from the array via chartSparkline.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);

Comment: Both are about the Axes. To set a range you set x-axis Minimum and Maximum. To remove the labels you set `...LabelStyle.Enabled = false;` for both axes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the default WinForms Chart available from the framework? (from `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`).
If so, you could manipulate the X & Y axes either from code or from the UI. The key is that they're defined under `ChartAreas`.

**From the UI:** `Properties` > `ChartAreas` > `Axes`. From there you can hide the labels by turning off `Enabled`. Same with `Minimum` and `Maximum`, and a whole lot of other customisations.

They're obviously also available from code, which can be useful in case you want to play with the scaling at the arrival of each data point.

More reading on the ChartArea class in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea).